# Get Request Information from Promise Or Response Guzzle 6.0

Tags: php, promise, guzzle, guzzle6

I want to get information about the request I have sent, such as url, body sent etc. I am using the Async feature which uses promises (example below)

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

return  new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request\Request('POST', $this->getUrl(), $this->getHeaders(), $this->getBody());
```

Is there a way where I can get request information from the promise or from the response?

Reason I am asking this is because I need to store some information about the request in the database later on, which can not be done before I sent the request.

## What I tried so far is

- Getting the information from the promise with the following methods

  - `$promise->getRequest()`
  - `$pomise->Request`
  - `$promise->request`
  - `$promise->getHandlers()`

Thank you

Comment: Please show how you are sending requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize a new `Request` then you have to send it. It's not sent by default. A request is sent when a `Client` calls `send` method on it. When request is completed you have access to all information about response:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$request = new Request('GET', 'https://www.google.com');
$response = $client->send($request);

$response->getHeaders(); // array of all retreived headers
$response->getStatusCode(); // http status code 
$response->getReasonPhrase(); // http status phrase
```

and you initialized a wrong `Request` object, Guzzle is not shipped with `\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request\Request` but `\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request`.

Now with a correct way of sending a request, getting request information is as simple as below:

```
print_r($request->getHeaders()); // array of all sent headers
echo $request->getUri(); // requested URI
```

Comment: But that will get the response information no? I want the request information that I sent to the request. Is my question not clear?

Comment: will give it a try and keep you updated. Thank you for the lead